How to TDD and fully test templated code that takes variadic number of arguments and which has specializations without code duplication in the tests?
Let's say I want to write a function that returns sum of passed positive numbers. Just returns 0 if I don't pass any.
And I decide that I want to pass arguments just as a list of arguments and as a vector. The list of arguments version just creates a vector of those and then passes it to the vector version of the function that has all the implementation of it.
Here's the test case and the function implementation:
#include <numeric>

template<typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Type>>>
std::size_t AddNumbers(std::vector<Type> Integers) {
    auto Sum = std::reduce(Integers.begin(), Integers.end());

    return Sum;
}

template<typename... Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral<Type>...>>>
std::size_t AddNumbers(Type... Integers) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> IntegerSequence{(std::size_t)Integers...};
    return AddNumbers(IntegerSequence);
}

TEST_CASE("Sum Test") {
    SECTION("When passed no numbers, returns 0") {
        auto Sum1 = AddNumbers();
        auto Sum2 = AddNumbers(std::vector<int>{});
        CHECK(Sum1 == 0);
        CHECK(Sum2 == 0);
    }

    SECTION("When passed 1 number, returns the number") {
        auto Sum1 = AddNumbers(1);
        auto Sum2 = AddNumbers(std::vector<int>{ 1 });

        CHECK(Sum1 == 1);
        CHECK(Sum2 == 1);
    }

    SECTION("When passed 2 numbers, returns the sum of numbers") {
        auto Sum1 = AddNumbers(1, 2);
        auto Sum2 = AddNumbers(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2 });

        CHECK(Sum1 == 3);
        CHECK(Sum2 == 3);
    }
}

As you can see, the tests are absolutely duplicated. I don't understand how to get rid of this duplication. This is just an example, but the real project code is similar. If I remove any of the test code, I think I can break the code, so testing just the non-vector version and assuming that it gets passed is not good enough IMO. Also, in the real project it's more complicated than this and I'd like to test all the versions.

When overloading a function template with SFINAE you can't use a default type template parameter for the SFINAE.  Instead you need to make it a non-type template parameter and give it a default value.  That would change template<typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Type>>> to template<typename Type, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Type>, bool> = true> and the same translation for your other function.  Not sure if that will fix your problem or not but it is something that should be addressed.

"the tests are absolutely duplicated." Create sub functions if your testing-framework allows it. (template <std::size_t... Is> void TestAddNumber(std::string sectionName, int expected) {/**/})

Reminder: we don't do TDD because the ceremony has some benefit of itself; we test drive the designs to get the results.
So what I would normally expect to see of an experienced TDD developer trying to approach a design like this would be something like:
First, test drive an implementation of
template<typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Type>>>
std::size_t AddNumbers(std::vector<Type> Integers);

Then, test drive an implementation of
template<typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Type>>>
std::vector<Type> ToVector(Type... Integers)

And finally, write this without tests, because it falls under the umbrella of "so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies" (by which I mean, there aren't going to be any subtle logic errors hidden within the design).
template<typename... Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral<Type>...>>
std::size_t AddNumbers(Type... Integers) {
    return AddNumbers(ToVector(Integers));
}

See also I get paid for code that works (Kent Beck, 2008)

What can make sense in some cases is to use the pair of methods as an oracle for each other
CHECK(AddNumbers(1, 2) == AddNumbers(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2 }))

This is essentially an application "different paths, same destination" as described by Scott Wlaschin.
For "toy" problems, like reducing a list, it doesn't necessarily buy you very much; but for problems where the calculations are subtle, and generating data samples is cheap, you can get a lot of mileage out of this.
To avoid the duplication of the 1, 2 value, you'd probably fall back on source code generation (or in trivial cases, using the preprocessor).  Or, if the number of instances was small and readily checked by eye, just leave it in place.
